# Regularity for this variational problem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

**The Problem.** Assume $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ bounded and $u \in H^1(\Omega,\mathbb{C})$ is some fixed function. Now consider the variational problem $$ F_\lambda(v) = \frac{\lambda}{2} \int_{\Omega} \vert u-v \vert^2 + \frac{1}{2} \int_\Omega \vert Dv \vert^2+ \frac{1}{4} \int_\Omega (1-\vert v \vert^2)^2,$$ i.e. $$F_\lambda (v)  = \int_\Omega L(Dv,v,x)$$ where $$ L(p,z,x)=\frac{\lambda}{2} \vert u(x)-z \vert^2+\frac{1}{2}\vert p \vert^2+\frac{1}{4}(1-\vert z \vert^2)^2. $$ Writing this as a system of real and imaginary part, I already showed that there is a solution and the associated Euler-Lagrange equation is $$ -\Delta v=\lambda(u-v)+v(1-\vert v \vert^2). \tag{1}$$

Therefore -my professor said- we infer that any solution $v$ to this variational problem is smooth.

**The Question.** How can we infer that?

**What I tried so far.** Every solution to the variational problem is a weak solution to (1), i.e. to a quasilinear elliptic equation. Now, regularity theory to quasilinear equations seems not to be very powerful. I read the relevant chapters of [this](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0098277/page/1) and [this](http://books.google.de/books/about/Multiple_Integrals_in_the_Calculus_of_Va.html?id=JwSAewaYsdMC&redir_esc=y) book, but they only give me rather weak Hölder continuity. However, [Evans](http://books.google.de/books/about/Partial_Differential_Equations.html?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&redir_esc=y) states in chapter 8.3.2 that in some cases the solution is $C^\infty$ if only $L$  is $C^\infty$.

Is there a result that lets me infer smoothness? Is there some property of my equation that I have missed? Any hint to some literature would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should note that you have a *semilinear* equation, not a quasilinear one.

Once you have $v \in H^1(\Omega)$, define $f = \lambda \, (u - v) + v \, (1-|v|^2)^2$ and observe $f \in W^{1,p}$, for some $p < 2$. This can be used to prove $v \in W^{3,p}$, if your domain is smooth enough.

Then, by bootstrapping, you get $f \in H^1$ (this is limited by the regularity of $u$!) and obtain $v \in H^3$. However, due to the regularity $u \in H^1$, you cannot do better. If $u$ would be more regular, than $v$ would also be more regular.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks again, but I have trouble understanding the argument. Is there an easy way to show that $f \in W^{1,p}$ for some $p<2$? I can indeed show that $f \in W^{1,\frac{2}{5}}$, but only by long computations. Do you have any hint for me? Sorry to bother you with such beginner's questions, but I have very little experience with Sobolev embeddings.

Comment: The term which makes trouble is $v \, (1- |v|^2)^2$. Here, you can use that $H^1(\Omega)$ embeds into $L^p(\Omega)$ for all $p < \infty$ and a product rule for weak derivatives.